# CSS to center image without resizing?

Tags: html, css

Are there any CSS tricks to center an image in a set width/height without resizing the image?

For example If I try to put the following image into a 150 x 150 conatiner it gets resized.

Original

[image]

Container

[image]

**I'm trying to achieve this**:

[image]

Can this be achieved with CSS alone?

Comment: or set the image as the background-image in css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it as a background image and use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position).

```
#foo {
  width: 150px;
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP0dH.jpg');
  height: 150px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aqirin/1/edit)

Comment: Is this the preferred method over overflow:hidden?

Comment: Yes. This is standard CSS and is supported by all browsers.

Comment: So if my images are dynamically loaded I'll need to specify each and every path correct?

Comment: You can use JS to set the background image just as easily as creating a new img element and setting its src. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329271/set-background-image-of-a-css-element

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:
html:

```
<div class="container">
<img src='' />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
max-height: 150px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -75px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without knowing the actual image size because they are all different. Thanks!